# Making a .ksh shell script to list out the files in the directory and put them in a .lst file (UNIX)

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to make a shell script .ksh file in unix that looks in a certain directory for a list of files, ( same as if you were to do an "ls" command) and take the naming convention of those files and put them into a .lst file or txt file to be read from. All the files have a .zip extension in my case, so it will be easier to look at. So in other words. I want it to...

Take from this static directory:

cd appl/b50devl/infa_shared/Temp/Disc_hist/

All the files in this directory are ex:

Filename1.zip
Filename2.zip
Filename3.zip

Then I want to copy all the names in this folder, make a .lst file in the same folder and paste it into the .lst file and save it. Mind you if we add another file like Filename4.zip, I want it to recreate the process overwriting the old .lst file.

So towards the end in that same directory I would have a file called AllFileName.lst or AllFileName.txt with a text list of:

Filename1.zip
Filename2.zip
Filename3.zip

Comment: are we only looking for `*.zip` files, or could there be other filename formats we're interested in (eg, FilenameX.txt, FilenameY.tgz, etc)? what if the directory in question has sub-directories? do you want the contents of the sub-directories (and any sub-sub-directories, etc) included in `AllFleName.txt`? should the directory names be added to `AllFileName.txt`?  and what about dot files (eg, `.otherfile.zip`) ... ignore or include in `AllFileName.txt`? what the heck, while we're at it ... what about fifo's/pipe's, links, and any other interesting types of 'files'?

Comment: No sub directories. The other answer gave me a good syntax to use. Basically this path will only have zip files. I just needed a script command to gather the list of those .zips and put them in a text file document that lists out each zip file.

Answer (score 0):

i think think this is the solution:

`#!/bin/bash

ls $1 > /AllFileName.txt`

the first argument is your directory

Comment: Yep yep.

ls $appl/b50devl/infa_shared/Temp/Disc_hist/* > /AllFileName.txt works. :) 

Had to make sure I included the asterisk. Thanks!

Comment: if this answer helped you, please  rate it as a good answer! thanks!

Comment: Rated! Appreciate the help, once again!